# Lomuto Partition in Quick Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

All of the Lomuto Partion implementations of Quick Sort have two swaps. Can we just use one swap, and delete the swap codes that outside the for loop? When j == high, the code can swap arr[high] with arr[i]. Following is my code:

```
1. Original LomutoPartion() implementation:
    int lomutoPartition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {   
        int pivot = arr[high]; 
        int i = (low-1);
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
        {   
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {   
                i++;
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr[high - 1];
        arr[high - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;

        return i;
    }

2. My LomutoPartition() implementation:
    int lomutoPartition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {   
        int pivot = arr[high]; 
        int i = (low-1);
        for (int j = low; j <= high; j++)
        {   
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {   
                i++;
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: Why? What's one swap more or less among thousands, perhaps even millions? Also, your logic looks a little strange to me - are your arrays 1-based here?

Comment: I mean the implementation of the code. In original Lomuto Partion algorithm, after for loop it swaps arr[high - 1] and arr[i]. But I think this swap can be merged in the for loop as my LomutoPartition() implemenration.

Comment: Please factor out a procedure `swap()` to make your point easier to see. (It might help to put one brace around a controlled code block in the line of the control expression, too.)